# Google app engine and django templates: passing entity ids to the template engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I have the following model:

```
class Messages(db.Model):
    name: db.StringProperty()
    ...
```

which uses the id field provided by the datastore of Google App Engine as a unique key, and it can be obtained by:

```
message = Message()
...
message.put()
...
id = message.key().id()
```

Now I would like to list the messages using the Django template system:

```
messages = db.Messages.all()
self.response.out.write(template.render('page.html', 'messages': messages))
```

And in the 'page.html':

```
{% for message in messages %}
   {{message.name}}
   {{message.id}}
   ....
{% endfor %}
```

However, the 'message.id' is always empty in the above loop. How to I pass the entity id's to the template system such that I may use them in the web page? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template code is no different in that you still need to access [the `id` instance-method of the key](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key_id).

Try instead:

```
{% for message in messages %}
   {{ message.name }}
   {{ message.key.id }}
   <!-------- ^^^ -->
{% endfor %}
```

---

The syntax, if you use Jinja2 templates (instead of Django templates), would be:

```
{% for message in messages %}
   {{ message.name }}
   {{ message.key().id() }}
   <!-------- ^^^^^ -->
{% endfor %}
```